# Why use "has knocked here"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Everybody believes that Reggie is the one who "has knocked" Chris down after the Big Game. Can we say "knocked". If not can anyone tell me why use "has knocked" here. Thank you.

Comment: Where did you get this text from? All I can think of is that prior context establishes as a known fact that Chris was "knocked down" by *someone* (possibly, *during* the Big Game, but that's just one possible assumption, not explicitly stated). I think it's highly unlikely ***knocked down*** here is a *literal* usage (meaning *hit so hard he fell to the ground*), but without the original context we're just guessing. My guess is it means Chris was metaphorically knocked down from his position as ***the top player*** (displaced by Reggie, who's now "top dog"). But that really is just ***IMHO***.

Comment: If you interpret the verb "to knock" literally (as in the person was physically knocked down), then you can say just "knocked" and the "has" isn't necessary, but to really be able to tell, you'd need more context. **Please add more context**

Comment: Here is the full text - In the novel ' Captain Nobody', Reggie Ratner is an antagonist to Chris Newman. Chris is Newy's brother, and he has been in a coma. Everybody believes that Reggie is the one who "has knocked" Chris down after the Big Game.